# putting variable into specific rows after math

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am trying to create a golf tourney scoreboard where i input the scores from each round and if i put in what course was played, it will go into the row of my sql database. how do i make a total score that is figured out in my php code go into a row that i specify on the form?

the form is built out like this:

```
<input name='name/handi/par/course/hole1/etc' type='text'>
```

to save space/time just short-handing the coding as much as possible. the php looks like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name/handi/par/course/hole1/etc'];
```

then i have the math broken out to figure the front 9, back 9, total score (with handicap [handi] worked in)

```
$totOut = ($hole1 + $hole2...etc) 
$totIn = ($hole10 + $hole11 ... etc) 
$total = ($totOut + $totIn) - $handi; 
$o_u_total = $total - $par; (over/under for the week)
$o_u_today = $total - $par; (over/under for the day)
```

the total for today (b/c there are 4 rounds) and the total for the whole week. the totals for the whole week are worked out in a query on the display page:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, 
SUM(total) AS Score, 
SUM(o_u_total) AS Over_Under, 
total AS Total_Today, 
o_u_today AS Over_Under_Today 
FROM matchplay 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY Score ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

and how i am trying to make the inputted value (course name) go into the specific row (designated in my sql dbase) is like this:

```
$ridge;
if ($_POST['course'] = 'The Ridge') {
($ridge = $total);
} 
$cove; 
if ($_POST['course'] = 'The Cove') {
($cove = $total);
} etc
```

i have a feeling that i am doing something terribly wrong with the if/else, but i don't know how else to choose what i want the $total to go into.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out ... thanks if anybody saw it and was in the middle of thumping me on the head with how easy it was

```
$ridge;
if ($_POST['course'] == 'The Ridge') {
($ridge = $total);
}
```

and not

```
$ridge;
if ($_POST['course'] = 'The Ridge') {
($ridge = $total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you did figure it out. To enhance your code and avoid multiple ifs, you can use a switch case statement.

```
$course_name = $_POST['course'];
switch($course_name){
  case ('The Ridge'):
    // your code here 
    break;
  case ('The code'):
    // an other code here
    break;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: that makes so much sense! thank you @mdamia!! i'll give it a try - just got so focused on making the if/else work didn't think of other option